# Entity Framework unitofwork vs self-tracking entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This questions stems from a n-tier application.  (non-WCF - only separate assemblies)

Should I use a unitofwork pattern and keep my object context around for entity change tracking?

or

Should I use self-tracking entities and always dispose my object context after a query, insert, delete, etc... and have the entities track themselves?

If I go with the second question do I need to use POCO?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something similar to unit of work pattern even though self-tracking entities would also work.

And

I do not need to use POCO entities for them to be self tracking I just have to have a partial class inherit from the base class for self tracking entities.